# Clang: Template deduction failed 'double' vs '<double>'

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, function-templates

Consider the following code, which uses a function with variable arguments:

```
#include <iostream>

// Typedef function type
template<typename... Output>
using Func = void(Output*...);

// Function runner
template<typename... Output>
void run_func(Func<Output...>& func, Output*... output) {
  for (int i=0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {
    func(output...);
  }
}

void f(double* d) {
  *d *= 2;
};

int main() {
  double value = 1.0;
  run_func(f, &value);
  printf("%f\n", value);
}
```

Compiling this with g++ 4.7.3 works fine, and running produces `1024.0` as expected.

Compiling using icpc 14.0.2 crashes it...

```
templ.cc(21): internal error: assertion failed: lower_expr: bad kind (shared/cfe/edgcpfe/lower_il.c, line 18582)

    run_func(f, &value);
    ^
```

Compiling with clang 3.5.0-1 gives the following error message:

```
templ.cc:21:3: error: no matching function for call to 'run_func'
  run_func(f, &value);
  ^~~~~~~~
templ.cc:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Output' ('double' vs. <double>)
void run_func(Func<Output...>& func, Output*... output) {
     ^
```

Is this a bug, or should have g++ not compiled this?

Why is clang deducing these "conflicting" types of `double` and `<double>`, is `<double>` meant to represent an unpacked arglist for example?

**Update** icpc 14.0.3 does not crash, and the program compiles and runs correctly.

See DPD200244439 at [Intel® Composer XE 2013 SP1 Compilers Fixes List](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-composer-xe-2013-compilers-sp1-fixes-list)

Comment: Your last question you could answer yourself by passing run_func(f,&value,&value)... which results in <double,double> which I don't think is correct... you might want to try with a more recent clang from svn, it smells like a bug

Comment: Since replacing the `template using` with the native type makes the problem go away, it feels very much like a bug.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I tried clang version 3.5.0 (trunk 208562), same problem!

Comment: a newer version of icpc fixes the issue

Comment: @WaelJ: In this case, I suggest that you report a bug to the Clang team. 3.5 is near, it would be cool if they managed to fix this before it goes out.

Comment: I filed a [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19802)

Comment: @WaelJ please post your update as an answer and accept it to get the question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the above discussion, it seems that this is indeed a bug in clang.

As pointed out by [gha.st](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65678/gha-st), skipping `template using` and using the native function type directly works:

```
void run_func(void (&func)(Output*...), Output*... output) {
```

I have a filed a bug against this [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19802).